# How to access the file which I saved in internal storage

Tags: android, android-internal-storage

I want to write a program that saves a file in mobile with some content. The problem is that I am not able to see the file in file manager in mobile. How to see that and in which folder?

Here is the code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String fileName = "MyFile";
        String content = "hello world";

        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_APPEND);
            outputStream.write(content.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit 1: Updated Code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    String content = "hello world";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   File f= getExternalFilesDir("arnav");
        Toast.makeText(this,""+f,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
File f1=new File(f,"ank.txt");
        FileOutputStream outputStream = null;
        try {
            outputStream = openFileOutput(f1.getAbsolutePath(), Context.MODE_APPEND);
            outputStream.write(content.getBytes());
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that folder (arnav) is getting created but file (ank.txt) is not getting created?How to solve?

Answer (score 1):

The "openFileOutput()" method will save the file in this path: /data/data/package-name/files/
You aren't able to see the file because "/data/data" directory is protected, only the mobile in root mode that can be seen.

Comment: then what to do to save the file in mobile so that it is visible to me in file manager

Comment: you could save the file in the external storage. "Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()" it returns the primary shared/external storage directory. Then it is visible in file manager.

Comment: but it should save in internal storage also as if sd card is not present then my file will not be shown?

Comment: yes, it will not be shown, except root your device. If you got root permission, use "RE" file manager.

Answer (score 0):

To access the files stored through the app  you need to go to the following location : *Internal Storage>Android>data>com.package_name.app_name>files* and here you can find the data saved by the app.

Comment: The problem is that the   "com.package_name.app_name" is not getting created in this case. Have I done anything wrong. Do I need to provide any permissions in manifest?

Comment: It should get created. Such a file will always get created for the app data. Please check it carefully, you Internal storage of your device.

Answer (score 0):

```
 MainActivity.this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
```

will return your file path created by
 `openFileOutput`